# Почему добавляется __PROTO__, как создать чистый массив без __PROTO__?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, prototype

Почему добавляется `__PROTO__`, как создать чистый массив без `__PROTO__`?

Массив генерируется примерно таким методом:

```js
let obj = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  obj[i] = {'test': i};
}
console.log(obj);
```

При использовании потом `$.each(obj, function(i, item){ ... });` идет бесконечный цикл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _При использовании потом $.each(obj, function(i, item){ ... }); идет бесконечный цикл_ - нет не идет, код в вопросе бесконечный цикл не может дать. https://jsfiddle.net/xs3fhcq5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`__proto__`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) это *устаревшее* свойство для получения прототипа объекта, расположено оно в `Object.prototype` так как `Array` является наследником `Object` создать массив без этого свойства - невозможно.

Comment: а как можно чистый json создать? мне главное чтобы только чисто данные нужны, без всяких лишних объектов

Comment: мне чисто потом только прогонять через $.each на jquery, неважно это будет объект, массив или json

Comment: @SergeyMironov, json создается с помощью [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) - на выходе получаешь нужную тебе строку. То что ты смотришь в консоли браузера - это то как, например хром, решил тебе показать **сам объект**

Comment: понял, спасибо, впервые с таким столкнулся

Comment: @SergeyMironov _мне чисто потом только прогонять через $.each на jquery,_ - в это случае тебе `__proto__` не помешает, так как это не перечисляемое свойство, соответственно он не попадет в перебор

Answer (score 2):

Пустой массив:

```
const obj = []
```

является представителем класса Array, исходя из чего он имеет прототип благодаря [прототипному наследованию](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype-inheritance) в JavaScript.